# How many sequences of length $2n$ can you make with 0-9 if none of the numbers appear $n$ times in a row?

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, permutations

I tried to find the total number of sequences and then minus of those with $n$ number of the same elements in a row. It seems extremely tedious so I'm wondering if anyone has a better approach to this problem?

Comment: no matter how tedious is ur work on solution, add it to your post

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are $10^{2n}$ sequences in total, and we can count the number of sequences with at least $n$ consecutive digits the same by classifying them according to the digit $k$ where the string starts:

1) If $k=1$, the first $n$ digits are the same, so there are $10\cdot10^n$ possibilities.

2) If $2\le k\le n+1$, there are $10^{k-1}$ choices for the first $k-1$ digits, 9 choices for the next $n$ digits, and

$\;\;\;\;10^{n-k+1}$ choices for the remaining digits, giving $n(9\cdot10^n)=(9n)10^n$ possibilities.

Since the $10\cdot9$ sequences with the first n digits the same and the second n digits the same (but differing from the first n) have been counted twice, there are a total of

$\color{blue}{10^{2n}-10^n(10+9n)+90=(10^n-9n-10)10^n+90}$ such strings.

Comment: Why, in 2), do we have only 9 choices for the next $n$ digits?

Also, didn't we double count the case where 1 number is repeated $n$ times and then immediately another number is repeated $n$ times? (You counted it once in 1), and again in 2) when $k = n+1$).

I really appreciate your help this though! Thanks.

Comment: Since the string starts at digit $k$, that digit must be different from the one before, so there are only 9 choices for it (when $k>1$).  [For example, if the digit in place $k-1$ is a 4, then the k-th digit can be any digit except 4.]  Since the string starts at digit $k$, the only sequences being counted twice are those that have the same digit in the first n places and then a different digit in all of the last n places.

Comment: @lsy You're welcome -- I'm glad this helped.

Answer (score 2):

We have the following generating function of these sequences
with $u$ marking runs and $z$ marking elements:

$$G(z, u) = 
\sum_{q\ge 0} \left(u(z+z^2+z^3+\cdots+z^{n-1})\right)^q
\\ = \sum_{q\ge 0} u^q z^q \left(\frac{1-z^{n-1}}{1-z}\right)^q
= \frac{1}{1-uz(1-z^{n-1})/(1-z)}
\\ = \frac{1-z}{1-z-uz(1-z^{n-1})}.$$

Now a sequence consisting of $k$  runs and hence marked with $u^k$ can
have $10\times 9^{k-1}$ possible  choices of elements.  We thus obtain
from the generating function

$$H(z) =
10\left. \frac{1}{u} \frac{1-z}{1-z-uz(1-z^{n-1})}\right|_{u=9}
= \frac{10}{9} \frac{1-z}{1-z - 9z(1-z^{n-1})}
\\ = \frac{10}{9} \frac{1-z}{1- 10z+ 9z^{n}}.$$

We thus have for the answer
$$[z^{2n}] H(z) =
[z^{2n}] \frac{10}{9} \frac{1-z}{1- 10z+ 9z^{n}}$$

which yields the follwing sequence starting at $n=1:$

$$0, 7290, 963090, 99540090, 9994500090, 999936000090, 
\\ 99999270000090, 9999991800000090, 999999909000000090, 
\\ 99999999000000000090, \ldots$$

Now to study  the asymptotics of this we note first  that $z=1$ is not
in fact a pole  of $H(z)$ and moreover that for $n$  large the term in
$10z$ dominates, creating a pole that is very close to $1/10.$

In fact we can apply  Rouche's theorem with $f(z) = 1-10z+9z^n$ and
$g(z) = -10z$ on the circle $|z|=1/2$ getting

$$|f(z)-g(z)| = |1+9z^n| \le 1+9\times 2^{-n}
\quad\text{and}\quad
|g(z)| = |-10z| = 5.$$

We have  $1+9\times 2^{-n} \lt 5$  when $n\ge 2$ and  hence $f(z)$ has
the same  number of  roots inside $|z|=1/2$  as $g(z)$ and  $g(z)$ has
just one root  there, namely zero, so $f(z)$ does as  well and this is
the pole $\rho$ close to $1/10.$

With this being the pole  closest to zero its inverse dominates the
coefficients of $H(z)$ asymptotically. The contribution comes from

$$\frac{1}{z-\rho} \mathrm{Res}_{z=\rho} H(z)
= - \frac{10}{9} \frac{1}{\rho} \frac{1}{1-z/\rho} 
\frac{1-\rho}{9n\rho^{n-1} - 10}
\\ = - \frac{10}{9} \frac{1}{1-z/\rho} 
\frac{1-\rho}{9n\rho^{n} - 10\rho}
= - \frac{10}{9} \frac{1}{1-z/\rho} 
\frac{1-\rho}{n(10\rho -1) - 10\rho}.$$

We require  some more  data on $\rho.$  Starting Newton's  method with
$\rho_0 = 1/10$ we get

$$\rho_{q+1} = \rho_q - \frac{f(\rho_q)}{f'(\rho_{q})}
= \rho_q - \frac{1-10\rho_q+9\rho_q^n}{-10+9n\rho_q^{n-1}}.$$

This yields

$$\rho_1 = \frac{1}{10}
+ \frac{9/10^n}{10-9n/10^{n-1}}
= \frac{1}{10} + \frac{9}{10^{n+1}-90n}.$$

Using this convergent to $\rho$ we finally obtain 
the approximation

$$-\frac{10}{9} \rho^{-2n}
\frac{1-\rho}{n(10\rho -1) - 10\rho}.$$

which produces the sequence

$$0, 7316, 963099, 99540092, 9994500090, 999936000090, 
\\ 99999270000090, 9999991800000090, 999999909000000090,
\\ 99999999000000000090,\ldots$$

where we have rounded to the nearest integer. The values are seen to be
exact starting at $n=5.$

**Remark.** The  following code computes  the first four terms  of the
sequence and  was used  to verify the  generating function  and detect
potential mistakes in the algebra.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>


int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
  int mx = 4;

  if(argc == 2){
    mx = atoi(argv[1]);

    if(mx < 1){
      fprintf(stderr, 
              "max val out of range: %d", mx);
      exit(-1);
    }
  }

  int n; long ind, val;

  for(n=1, val=100; n <= mx; n++){
    long res = 0;

    for(ind=0; ind < val; ind++){
      int pos, d[2*n]; long extr = ind;

      for(pos = 0; pos < 2*n; pos++){
        d[pos] = extr % 10;
        extr = (extr - d[pos])/10;
      }

      int runlen, cur = -1;

      pos = 0;
      while(pos < 2*n){
        if(d[pos] != cur){
          runlen = 1; cur = d[pos];
        }
        else{
          runlen++;
        }

        if(runlen >= n) break;

        pos++;
      }

      if(!(pos < 2*n || runlen >= n)) res++;
    }

    printf("%02d: %ld\n", n, res);

    val *= 100;
  }


  return 0;
}
```